# Microsoft Teams webhook payload contains unusable Teams ID

Tags: httprequest, webhooks, microsoft-teams

I have created an outgoing webhook for MS Teams. I pointed this to an Azure Function App which checks the authentication token and then forwards the payload through another webhook to a Flow (Power Automate) which replies to the original message in Teams.

This post addresses only one of the many problems this roadmap has, namely that the payload contains (amongst much else) the Teams Message ID, the Teams Channel ID and the Teams Team ID, as follows:

**messageid=1578517604597** CORRECT. This is great
**teamsChannelId=19:99c0a47caa884ffeabefc59305523414@thread.skype**. This may look wierd but it's correct
**teamsTeamId=19:c374b6b6d8cf4f17a9c77cd45399e90c@thread.skype** Well this appears to just be wrong.
If I ask Flow to post a reply to the message on teams it will complain that the group ID is incorrect. It is referring to the Team ID.

If I open the original teams message in a browser and look at the URL I find the message ID and the channel ID as above. But the groupID is as follows:
**groupId=006ff9ad-fdcc-4705-b651-93eef04361dc**
Putting this in Flow works!

But if I search for this value in the JSON payload it is nowhere to be found!
Can it somehow be derived from the TeamID?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: To post any message in the channel, you need the channelID. GroupID and TeamID will not help you post message in any particular channel.
How the payload is getting generated?